# Distributed training of tensorflow using tf.train.Server and tf.distribute.MirroredStrategy

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, reinforcement-learning, tensorflow1.15

I am trying to implement a reinforcement learning algorithm in TensorFlow 2 by referring to its implementation in TensorFlow 1.

In the algorithm I need to use distributed training. In tf1 the implementation I am referring to uses `tf.train.Server` and I want to use `tf.distribute.MirroredStrategy` instead. However, I am not able to find if there is a link between them. I think both of them are for distributed learning but how similar they are to each other? Or how different they are from each other?

The code in github can help to understand the question better ([here](https://github.com/deepmind/scalable_agent/blob/master/experiment.py))  around line number 468-483:

```
def train(action_set, level_names):
  """Train."""

  if is_single_machine():
    local_job_device = ''
    shared_job_device = ''
    is_actor_fn = lambda i: True
    is_learner = True
    global_variable_device = '/gpu'
    server = tf.train.Server.create_local_server()
    filters = []
  else:
    local_job_device = '/job:%s/task:%d' % (FLAGS.job_name, FLAGS.task)
    shared_job_device = '/job:learner/task:0'
    is_actor_fn = lambda i: FLAGS.job_name == 'actor' and i == FLAGS.task
    is_learner = FLAGS.job_name == 'learner'

    # Placing the variable on CPU, makes it cheaper to send it to all the
    # actors. Continual copying the variables from the GPU is slow.
    global_variable_device = shared_job_device + '/cpu'
    cluster = tf.train.ClusterSpec({
        'actor': ['localhost:%d' % (8001 + i) for i in range(FLAGS.num_actors)],
        'learner': ['localhost:8000']
    })
    server = tf.train.Server(cluster, job_name=FLAGS.job_name,
                             task_index=FLAGS.task)
    filters = [shared_job_device, local_job_device]
    ...
```

Comment: You may refer to [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/distributed_training) link to understand the difference with Parameter Server(PS) and Mirrored Strategy. But remember the cluster configuration for both the strategies isn't same. Use the Strategy based on your machine configuration. If one machine has attached multiple GPUs use Mirror Strategy, if multiple GPU devices and Parameter Server are connected via network use PS strategy.

Comment: Thank you, I was using tf.train.Server.create_local_server() I do not have gpu with me I am trying to run the code on single machine. For mirrored strategy is it necessary to have a gpu?

Comment: Also where can I find the difference between these two methods.

Comment: Yes, for Mirror strategy, multiple GPUs are needed in a single machine, if you have only one CPU device, there is no need to use any distribution strategy